# How can I determine the number of trees in random Forest in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random-forest

In Matlab, we train the random forest by using `TreeBagger()` method. One of the parameters of this method is the number of trees. I am using random forest for classification approach. How can I determine the number of trees of random forest?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html ; checking the documentation is the very first thing one is expected to do, much before thinking of opening a question here -  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `computer-vision` or `image-processing` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer lies directly in the relevant documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html

Comment: @desertnaut The documentation says what the NumTrees argument is, but it doesn't states how to determine which value to use with a given problem

Comment: No one can determine that for any problem in general, plus that this is not a *programming* question (hence off-topic here), plus that your chosen wording is too vague...

Comment: I agree that the wording is vague, but I read this as a question for hints to determine this value. When you should increase it, when to decrease it, based on results. Nonetheless even if I read it correctly, maybe better place for this question would be [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you've been training this model, you should know the number of trees that used in the model because it must set as input for `TreeBagger()`.
 Anyway, for the learned model like `RFmodel`, you can use `compact(RFmodel)` to determine the number of trees.

This is regression example based on [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regression-treeBagger-examples.html#d120e75146) :

```
load imports-85;
Y = X(:,1);
X = X(:,2:end);
isCat = [zeros(15,1);ones(size(X,2)-15,1)]; % Categorical variable flag
rng(1945,'twister')
UnknownNumberofTrees=100;
RFmodel = TreeBagger(UnknownNumberofTrees,X,Y,'Method','R','OOBPred','On',...
        'Cat',find(isCat == 1),'MinLeaf',5);

RFmodelObject = compact(RFmodel);
RFmodelObject.NTrees

%ans =

%   100
```